# Store changes on git repository without committing

Tags: git

I am working on 2 separate machines in 2 different places, but on the same stuff, using the same git repository. I'm wondering if there is a way to store unfinished work (kind of like a stash), so that I can access it from the repository regardless of my machine. If this is not a good idea/not possible, can somebody recommend any practical solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a [branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell). Later, when you decide you are finished with whatever you do, you can [squash these commits](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits) and merge them back to master.